# A macro that calls 2 macros depending on the cell value

Tags: excel, vba

I have this chunk of code :

The macro that calls 2 other macros depending on the cell value is this :

```
    Option Explicit

    Function lastRow(col As Variant, Optional wks As Worksheet) As Long

        If wks Is Nothing Then
            Set wks = ActiveSheet
        End If

        lastRow = wks.Cells(wks.Rows.Count, col).End(xlUp).Row

    End Function

Sub runMacros()
    Dim vDat As Variant
    Dim i As Long

    Dim wks As Worksheet
    Set wks = ActiveSheet

    With wks
        vDat = .Range(.Cells(1, "G"), .Cells(lastRow("G"), "G"))
    End With

    For i = LBound(vDat) To UBound(vDat)
        If vDat(i, 1) = "First" Then
            Macro3
            Macro1
        ElseIf vDat(i, 1) = "Second" Then
            Macro3
            Macro2
        End If
    Next i

End Sub
```

The first macro that is being called is this(Macro3) - it just creates a new folder if it does not exist:

```
Sub Macro3()
Dim Path As String
Dim Folder As String
Path = "C:\Users\" & Environ("Username") & "\Desktop\Rejection Folder\"
Folder = Dir(Path, vbDirectory)

If Folder = vbNullString Then
    MkDir "C:\Users\" & Environ("Username") & "\Desktop\Rejection Folder\"
End If
End Sub
```

and then I have this macro:

```
    Sub Macro1()
Application.ScreenUpdating = False
Dim StrMMSrc As String, StrMMDoc As String, StrMMPath As String, StrName As String, SavePath As String, StrFileName As String, MailSubjectName As String
Dim i As Long, j As Long
Const StrNoChr As String = """*./\:?|"
Dim wdApp As New Word.Application, wdDoc As Word.Document

wdApp.Visible = False
wdApp.DisplayAlerts = wdAlertsNone
StrMMSrc = ThisWorkbook.FullName
SavePath = "C:\Users\" & Environ("Username") & "\Desktop\Rejection Folder\" 'Name of the folder
StrMMPath = ThisWorkbook.Path & "\"
StrMMDoc = StrMMPath & "RejectionLetterEmployee.docx" 'Name of the word file
Set wdDoc = wdApp.Documents.Open(Filename:=StrMMDoc, AddToRecentFiles:=False, ReadOnly:=True, Visible:=False)
With wdDoc
  With .MailMerge
    .MainDocumentType = wdFormLetters
    .OpenDataSource Name:=StrMMSrc, ReadOnly:=True, AddToRecentFiles:=False, _
      LinkToSource:=False, Connection:="Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;User ID=Admin;" & _
      "Data Source=StrMMSrc;Mode=Read;Extended Properties=""HDR=YES;IMEX=1"";", _
      SQLStatement:="SELECT * FROM `Rejection$`"
   For i = 1 To .DataSource.RecordCount
      .Destination = wdSendToNewDocument
      .SuppressBlankLines = True
      With .DataSource
        .FirstRecord = i
        .LastRecord = i
        .ActiveRecord = i
        If Trim(.DataFields("Name")) = "" Then Exit For
        StrName = .DataFields("Name") 'File name will be determined by this column name
        MailSubjectName = .DataFields("ID")
      End With
      .Execute Pause:=False
      For j = 1 To Len(StrNoChr)
        StrName = Replace(StrName, Mid(StrNoChr, j, 1), "_")
        MailSubjectName = Replace(MailSubjectName, Mid(StrNoChr, j, 1), "_")
      Next
      StrName = Trim(StrName)
      StrFileName = "C:\Users\" & Environ("Username") & "\Desktop\Rejection Folder\" & StrName
      With wdApp.ActiveDocument
        '.SaveAs Filename:=StrMMPath & StrName & ".docx", FileFormat:=wdFormatXMLDocument, AddToRecentFiles:=False 'Save as WORD file(not needed at the moment)
        ' and/or:
        '.SaveAs Filename:=StrMMPath & StrName & ".pdf", FileFormat:=wdFormatPDF, AddToRecentFiles:=False 'Save to the folder where the excel sheet exists(not needed)
        .SaveAs Filename:=SavePath & StrName & ".pdf", FileFormat:=wdFormatPDF, AddToRecentFiles:=False 'Save to the folder that has been created by Path_Exists function
        .Close SaveChanges:=False
  ' Set OutApp = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")
  ' Set OutMail = OutApp.CreateItem(0)
  '  On Error Resume Next
  '  With OutMail
     '   .To = ""
     '   .SentOnBehalfOfName = ""
     '   .CC = ""
     '   .BCC = ""
     '   .Subject = "ID" & " " & MailSubjectName & " " & StrName
     '   .BoDy = ""
      '  .Attachments.Add StrFileName & ".pdf"
    '    .Display
        '.Send
  '  End With
 '   On Error GoTo 0
 '  Set OutMail = Nothing
'   Set OutApp = Nothing
      End With
  '  Next i
    .MainDocumentType = wdNotAMergeDocument
  End With
  .Close SaveChanges:=False
End With
wdApp.DisplayAlerts = wdAlertsAll
wdApp.Quit
Set wdDoc = Nothing: Set wdApp = Nothing
Application.ScreenUpdating = False
End Sub
```

**Macro1 and Macro2 are the same code but they use a different Word file to create the PDF** - Macro1 runs if a cell in "G" column contains the string "first" and Macro2 runs if it contains "second".
The macros create a PDF file and sends it via Outlook.

The problem with Macro1 and Macro2 is that they have a For loop which runs through all rows which basically contradicts what I want to do based on a cell value.
I tried to tweak it a little but since im not familiar that much with VBA I couldnt make it run on the row based on the For loop that **runMacros()** executes when it calls the 2 other macros.
I only succeeded making it work only on the first row or the last row.

So my question is this : How would I fix Macro1 code to work on a row that runMacros() check.

For example : runMacros() is executed via button.
it checks if G2 cell contains either "first" or "second".

if it contains "first" it will run Macro3 and Macro1.
if it contains "second" it will run Macro3 and Macro2.

runMacros() will then go to the next row, check and execute the macros until it reaches an empty row.

currently Macro1 and Macro2 have a for loop which is wrong because if the G2 contains "first" and G3 contains "second" all the PDF files will be according to Macro2 because it just replaced what Macro1 did

I want Macro1 and Macro2 to follow the row that runMacros() is checking and only execute on that row.

How do I do that?

Comment: You can either pass in the `Range` you calculated in your `RunMacros` (`vDat`) along with the row number as parameters to `Macro1` and `Macro2`, or you can create an intermediate `Range` variable in `RunMacros` for just the one row you're referencing and pass that as a parameter to the other macros.

Comment: How exactly do I do that?
"You can either pass in the `Range` you calculated in your `RunMacros (vDat)` along with the row number as parameters to `Macro1` and `Macro2`"
I thought that variables die after the function ends so they cant really be used in another macro.

Comment: I tried using `i = .DataSource.RecordCount`
instead of `For i = 1 To .DataSource.RecordCount`
And it works only on the last row in my excel sheet instead of the row that runMacros() is currently on.

Comment: Is Column G on the 'Rejection' sheet with Name and ID ? If so does it also have column name ?

Comment: Column G name is "Status" : either he is an employee or an entrepreneur.
A to F  columns contain personal information(ID, Name, Address, etc.).

Answer (score 0):

In answering your question in passing parameters, there are a couple ways to do this. In the first example, create your `vDat` variable as a `Range`, then loop over the range and pass a range parameter.

```
Sub runMacros()
    Dim wks As Worksheet
    Set wks = ActiveSheet

    Dim vDat As Range
    With wks
        Set vDat = .Range("G1").Resize(lastRow("G"), 1)
    End With

    Dim i As Long
    For i = 1 To vDat.Rows.Count
        If vDat.Offset(i, 0).Value = "First" Then
            Macro3 vDat.Rows(i)
            Macro1 vDat.Rows(i)
        ElseIf vDat.Offset(i, 0).Value = "Second" Then
            Macro3 vDat.Rows(i)
            Macro2 vDat.Rows(i)
        End If
    Next i
End Sub

Private Sub Macro1(ByRef theRow As Range)
    Debug.Print "Macro1 row address = " & theRow.Address
End Sub

Private Sub Macro2(ByRef theRow As Range)
    Debug.Print "Macro2 row address = " & theRow.Address
End Sub

Private Sub Macro3(ByRef theRow As Range)
    Debug.Print "Macro3 row address = " & theRow.Address
End Sub
```

But you actually created `vDat` as an array, so you can just pass the value of that row in the array:

```
Sub runMacros()
    Dim wks As Worksheet
    Set wks = ActiveSheet

    Dim vDat As Variant
    With wks
        vDat = .Range("G1").Resize(lastRow("G"), 1).Value
    End With

    Dim i As Long
    For i = LBound(vDat, 1) To UBound(vDat, 1)
        If vDat(i, 0) = "First" Then
            Macro3 vDat(i, 0)
            Macro1 vDat(i, 0)
        ElseIf vDat(i, 0) = "Second" Then
            Macro3 vDat(i, 0)
            Macro2 vDat(i, 0)
        End If
    Next i
End Sub

Private Sub Macro1(ByVal theRowValue As Variant)
    Debug.Print "Macro1 row value = " & theRowValue
End Sub

Private Sub Macro2(ByVal theRowValue As Variant)
    Debug.Print "Macro2 row value = " & theRowValue
End Sub

Private Sub Macro3(ByVal theRowValue As Variant)
    Debug.Print "Macro3 row value = " & theRowValue
End Sub
```

What is not clear in your code and question is how the row relates to the `DataSource` or how you are using it in `Macro1` or `Macro2`. I would also suggest renaming your macros to something more descriptive to what action the macro is performing.

Comment: I used those names for simplicity.
The actual names are : 
`Macro1 is : RejectionEmployee`
`Macro2 is: RejectionEntrepreneur`
`Macro3 is: CreateRejectionFolder`

To be able to use the second code you have written, do I need to make any changes to RejectionEmployee() and RejectionEntrepreneur()?

To be frank I do not know what the DataSource does in my code because I did not write the code. I have been using the code from a website and tweaked it to work to my needs, if it needs to be changed I don't mind as long as it works I guess...thanks for the help, it is much appreciated

Comment: The `DataSource` section of your code is opening a MS Word document that is a Mail Merge result. So your code is basically using that mail merge document as a database to look for certain names I believe. How that relates to the values in the `vDat` array is up to you to figure out.

Comment: The code works perfectly fine, my issue is with giving the macros a condition to run based on the value in G column...vDat only check the value of cells in G column and runs a specific macro depending on the value.
When I run `runMacros()` it works but the issue is that the last row that every row that is being checked the macros overrides the files that it created the previous row because the macros run through all rows no matter what value is in G cell(because that is being checked only in `runMacros()`.

Answer (score 0):

With MailMerge you can create a batch of documents from a datasource. 
Using the Status column as a WHERE clause in the datasource SQL allows you to create the
documents with only 2 runs of the same subroutine using a parameter to apply the different template.

```vb
Option Explicit

Sub runMacros()

    Dim Template1 As String, Template2 As String, Path As String, Folder As String

    Template1 = ThisWorkbook.Path & "RejectionLetterEmployee.docx"
    Template2 = ThisWorkbook.Path & "RejectionLetterEntrepreneur.docx"

    ' create path for documents
    Path = "C:\Users\" & Environ("Username") & "\Desktop\Rejection Folder\"
    Folder = Dir(Path, vbDirectory)

    If Folder = vbNullString Then
       MkDir Path
    End If

    ' create documents
    CreateDocuments "First", Template1, Path
    CreateDocuments "Second", Template2, Path
    MsgBox "Ended"

End sub

Sub CreateDocuments(Status As String, Template As String, SavePath)

    MsgBox "Running macro for Status = [" & Status & "] using " & Template & vbCrLf & _
           " into Folder " & SavePath, vbInformation

    Const StrNoChr As String = """*./\:?|"

    ' Paths and Filename
    Dim strMMSrc As String, strMMDoc As String, strMMPath As String
    Dim StrFileName As String, t0 As Single
    t0 = Timer

    ' open template
    Dim wdApp As New Word.Application, wdDoc As Word.Document, i As Integer, j As Integer
    Dim strName, MailSubjectName

    wdApp.Visible = False
    wdApp.DisplayAlerts = wdAlertsNone
    Set wdDoc = wdApp.Documents.Open( _
        Filename:=Template, _
        AddToRecentFiles:=False, _
        ReadOnly:=True, _
        Visible:=False)

    strMMSrc = ThisWorkbook.FullName ' datasource name

    With wdDoc.MailMerge
        .MainDocumentType = wdFormLetters
        .Destination = wdSendToNewDocument
        .SuppressBlankLines = True

        .OpenDataSource Name:=strMMSrc, ReadOnly:=True, AddToRecentFiles:=False, _
             LinkToSource:=False, Connection:="Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;User ID=Admin;" & _
             "Data Source=strMMSrc;Mode=Read;Extended Properties=""HDR=YES;IMEX=1"";", _
             SQLStatement:=" SELECT * FROM `Rejection$` WHERE Status = '" & Status & "'"

        ' confirm to create docs
        If vbNo = MsgBox(.DataSource.RecordCount & " documents will be created in " & SavePath & _
                          ", continue ?", vbYesNo, "Confirm") Then
            GoTo skip
        End If

        ' create one doc for each record in datasource
        For i = 1 To .DataSource.RecordCount

            With .DataSource
                .FirstRecord = i
                .LastRecord = i
                .ActiveRecord = i

                strName = Trim(.DataFields("Name"))
                MailSubjectName = Trim(.DataFields("ID"))
                'Debug.Print "Raw", i, strName, MailSubjectName
                If strName = "" Then Exit For
            End With

            ' do merge
            .Execute Pause:=False

            ' construct doc filename to save
            ' replace illegal characters
            For j = 1 To Len(StrNoChr)
                strName = Replace(strName, Mid(StrNoChr, j, 1), "_")
                MailSubjectName = Replace(MailSubjectName, Mid(StrNoChr, j, 1), "_")
            Next
            Debug.Print "Cleaned ", i, strName, MailSubjectName

            'Save to the folder that has been created by Path_Exists function
             StrFileName = SavePath & strName
            With wdApp.ActiveDocument
                .SaveAs Filename:=SavePath & strName & ".pdf", _
                         FileFormat:=wdFormatPDF, AddToRecentFiles:=False
                .Close SaveChanges:=False
            End With

        Next i
        .MainDocumentType = wdNotAMergeDocument
    End With

    MsgBox i - 1 & " documents created in " & SavePath, vbInformation, "Completed in " & Int(Timer - t0) & " secs"

skip:
    ' cleanup
    wdDoc.Close SaveChanges:=False
    wdApp.DisplayAlerts = wdAlertsAll
    wdApp.Quit
    Set wdDoc = Nothing
    Set wdApp = Nothing

End Sub
```